# Is it possible to create shortcut icons for Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

Is it possible to create shortcut icons for frequently used tasks in Thunderbird?  For example, I would like to manually run a specific email filter.  It would be nice if it could be a one click event rather than Menu / Tools / msg filters / pick the filter / Run Now.

Answer (score 0):

There are extensions to add or modify buttons and icons such as [Phoenity](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/phoenity-buttons/?src=search) (which I've not used). Go to *Tools* | *Add-ons* in *Thunderbird*, and enter a search term such as "icon" or "shortcut". Note that in making things more secure, many older add-ons no longer work in newer versions of Thunderbird. However, authors are now rewriting these extensions to satisfy the new API... If you don't see a working add-on today, it may soon be available.